# Scroll visible content in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

How can I move the visible part of `JPanel`? I mean I have a set of tabs that can be dynamically created and closed (similar to browser tabs) and at some point there might be too much of them to be visible so I'd like to add buttons to move the view left and right. I thought about adding a `JScrollPane` with `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy=HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` but it results with quite ugly... scroll. How can I create just buttons to manipulate the visible part of the panel?

The code responsible for the tabs is pretty much something like this:

```
private JPanel tabsPane;

private JComponent createItemsPane() {
        tabsPane = new JPanel();
        tabsPane.setOpaque(false);
        tabsPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tabsPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        return tabsPane;
    }

public void addTab(TabCaption item) {
        tabsPane.add(item);
    }
```

Alternatively, I'd like to move the change the visible part so that selected tab is always displayed...

Comment: Do you know about [`JTabbedPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html)? (Not sure how that handles "overflowing" tabs, though)

Comment: I'm using some other implementation in existing project so it might be too risky... I thought about wrapping it with `JScrollPane` but the scrollbars look very ugly.

Comment: Just checked: `JTabbedPane` will "stack" tabs, i.e. create multiple rows of tabs if they do not fit into one row.

Comment: *"..but the scrollbars look very ugly."* Using which PLAF? I don't like Metal for a lot of reasons, and generally set the System PLAF.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't think it's the scrollbar's look, but the fact that there's a scrollbar _at all_ in the tabs bar that's ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the scrollbars to show, you can the the `vsb` and `hsbPolicy` accordingly. Then, add a bunch of buttons for manipulating the `JViewPort` of the `JScrollPane`:

```
JPanel comp = new JPanel();
comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 20));
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    comp.add(new JLabel(String.format("  %d", i)));
}

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(comp, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> setview = (x, y) -> {
    Point p = scroll.getViewport().getViewPosition();
    scroll.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(p.x + x, p.y + y));
};
JButton left = new JButton("<");
left.addActionListener(e -> setview.accept(-10, 0));
JButton right = new JButton(">");
right.addActionListener(e -> setview.accept(+10, 0));

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The Frame starts with size large enough, but if you shrink the window you can use the buttons to scroll. You might also want to disable or hide the buttons depending on the current viewport.

[image]